# Weird misalignment in some PC's only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website and the client wanted *exactly* the mockup. The problem is, the headers and some other divs that I've been using with a background are giving me some problems. And for the first time in my experience, it's not a browser-specific problem.

This is how my sister (I asked her to send me screenshots from another PC...) and I see it:

[image]

But, in every Mac, every mobile device, and the PC at my office, I see it like this:

[image]

As you can see, only in SOME Windows PCs, there's extra padding in top of the text. If I get rid of the padding-top of the titles, it comes back to "normal", only a pair of pixels thinner.

Here's the html for the title:

```
<div class="contentHeader"><b><div class="square"><!--&#9724;-->&nbsp;</div>IN PROMOTION</b></div>
```

And this, is the css of that part of the html:

```
.contentHeader{
    line-height: 38px;
    padding-top: 6.5px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    background-color: white;
    /*padding: 3px 8px;*/ /*In fact, if I uncomment this line, I'll see it centered, but not in the other ones...*/
    font-size: 20px; 
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.square{
    font-size:20px; 
    background-color: black;
    line-height: 15px; 
    min-height: 19px;
    min-width: 19px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    font-family: "Arial";
}
```

I'm open to any solutions... I already use jQuery for some things in this site, so it could be a fix if it really works.

I made sure that the cache is not the problem. And I tested it in my PC in Chrome, Firefox and Edge... everywhere's the same. As I said, I only saw that in my PC and my sister's. Both of us use Windows 10, and in my office I have Windows 10 too. Any ideas of the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top have padding and your bottom don't. I made both with the same padding:

```css
.contentHeader{
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    font-size: 20px; 
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background: skyblue;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.square{
    font-size:19px;
    background-color: black;
    line-height: 19px; 
    min-height: 19px;
    min-width: 19px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentHeader"><b><div class="square"><!--&#9724;-->&nbsp;</div>IN PROMOTION</b></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! In fact, both yours and Joseph's one are useful, as he made me remember some guidelines I forgot in terms of speed. Silly me. Thanks! But, some of you guys know why it happened? I mean... it's not a OS problem, and not a Browser problem neither. So... I don't know why it happened.

Comment: The stantard values of the elements arent the same through the browsers (seems like the Chrome developers aren't friend enought of Safari's developers to make a deal with universal values). So, in a example, if on Chrome the `<body>` tag have a margin-bottom of 5px by default and on Safari it have no margin, then you can't leave it's margin value empty, otherwise it will show up different in these browsers. Thats a common problem so webmasters did create files like **normalize.css** to reset the different browsers' standars to the same values.

Comment: You'll notice in some websites on the header: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

- First, don't use `<b>`. If you mean to bold the text, use `font-weight:bold` in CSS.
- Putting block-level elements in inline elements (a `<div>` in a `<b>`) will cause unexpected positioning. This is probably what's causing this, but we can't say for sure.
- Don't alter `line-height` for positioning purposes. That's solely for text spacing.
- Lastly, surround the text in a `<span>` and use `display:inline-block` on it  (so it obeys vertical paddings). That way, you can position both the square and the text with paddings as well as target it for `font-weight:bold`.

Try just this and work your way with just paddings and dimensions.

```
<div class="contentHeader">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <span class="promotion-text">IN PROMOTION</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I always forgot about the <b> being discontinued and such... but I get rid of the <b> and nothing changes. So, it's a <div> and text in a <div>, but it's exactly the same as before...

Thanks for the <b> / font-weight remainder, though!

Answer (score -2):

toss in some javascript code to read the info, and let it be placed in very bottom footer or some such.  it might give details of what is pushing what.

chrome / firefox both have built in or third party apps to install to "right click" and choose inspect. you might find something, some place within the "dom" tree.

=================
honestly not sure what you are talking about... the images you linked to. both show "scrolling" left/right and up/down or at least that is what it seems like.  good chance you are going out past "width" and/or "height" of the screen and causing scroll bars to happen per say.